# Can you paint over Olympic Rescue It?

Tags: repainting

Several years ago I painted our old concrete patio with *Olympic Rescue It! Wood Deck and Concrete Resurfacer*, and it has lasted very well. Now we have new cracks which we are filling in, and I'd like to paint over the Olympic product. We are in the process of listing the house for sale.